# Angularjs and Jquery: Angularjs routing and jquery script execution issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have tried using angularjs and jquery for developing my websites and i'm not new to them. but somehow i stumbled to an issue which is not so familiar for me.

the main problem is between angular routing and jquery document ready script execution.

the scenario is i use angularjs ui-router to browse pages for my website(SPA) one of my page has inline jquery codes looks like this

```
<div id="details-page">

</div>

<script>
    var counter = 0;

    function foo() {
        var setFoo = setInterval(function() {
            counter++;
            console.log(counter);
        }, 2000);
    }
</script>

foo();
```

the codes runs as expected,
but when i go route to another pages i can see my logs still running(the foo function) which seems weird for me but that's not the main problem, the main problem is when i go back to "details-page" the function foo is executed back(because of $(document).ready(function(){})) so two foo's is running in my system which is definitely destroyed everything.

so my goal here is how to STOP the old foo function or 
how to STOP the new function foo from executing in short i just want one foo function running in my system, thanks

Comment: The correct solution is to drop jQuery as Angular can easily do this. There's really no need for both of them to be in the same project.

Comment: i tried it also i use angular directive but problem still exist maybe because angular still java script i think it has to do with the callbacks function

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want this counter to start when the user enters the "details-page", you want it to keep running when they leave, and when they come back it must use the original counter.

To solve this with AngularJS you should create a service, as your service will be a singleton and not linked specifically to the "details-page".

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/UncleDave/g9co2172/1/

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('DetailsCtrl', function(counterService) {
    counterService.start();
  })
  .service('counterService', function($interval) {
    var counter = 0;
    var started = false;

    function start() {
      if (started)
        return;

      started = true;

      $interval(function() {
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
      }, 2000);
    }

    return {
      start: start
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DetailsCtrl as details">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in your controller,and don't forget t inject `$rootScope` and `$interval` services in your controller.

```
$rootScope.counter = 0;
var setFoo;

function foo() {
    setFoo = $interval(function () {
        $rootScope.counter++;
        console.log($rootScope.counter);
    }, 2000);
}

foo();

$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
    $interval.cancel(setFoo);
})
```